# Joining paths: TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python-3.x

```
@staticmethod
def get_abs_filename(filename):
    speak_result = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 
                                   os.pardir, filename))
    return speak_result
```

Can somebody please tel me what I'm doing wrong?

```
File "D:\Luan Van\Jennie\Jennie\TextManager\speaker.py", line 37, in get_abs_filename
    os.pardir, filename))
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ntpath.py", line 115, 
    in joingenericpath._check_arg_types('join', path, *paths)
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\genericpath.py", line 149,
    in _check_arg_types(funcname, s.__class__.__name__)) from None
TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'NoneType'
```

Comment: I suggest visiting [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to get a better insight on how to ask a solid question. Additionally, some code, errors, and a slightly better explanation is necessary in order for others to offer you help (they 1st need to understand what the actual issue is). Hang in there. You'll be great at this. ;)

Comment: debug (print them) the value of `__file__`, and `os.path.dirname(__file__)` and `os.pardir` and `filename` - one of them is None - some of them are constants so they wont be None - culprit is probably `filename` to begin with